# How to send an http POST multipart/form-data request with a file attached using Apache-nifi's InvokeHttp processor?

Tags: http, http-post, multipartform-data, apache-nifi

I am trying to send a multipart/form-data request to a POST API using Nifi's InvokeHTTP processor. This request takes a json and a file. The request headers and request body in POSTMAN look something like this -

```
POST /delivery/deliverPackage
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.1
Accept: */*
Host: example.hostname:port
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------161413078116998145311888
content-length: 1115
json={ "destinationProtocol" : "HL7", "destinationFormat": "HL7_V2_ORU", "destinationType": "example", "destinationConnectionParams":{ "URI": "example", "HOST": "example", "PORT": "example" } }file=[object Object]
```

where the file object contains the file details I am trying to send.

I want to send this multipart/form-data request in nifi. Based on an answer I saw on one of the forums (sorry do not have the link to it), I am trying to create this request body in the content of the flowfile using ReplaceText processor before sending the flowfile to an InvokeHttp processor. The flowfile content looks something like this -

```
POST /delivery/deliverPackage
User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
Accept: */*
Host: example.hostname:port
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------161413078116998145311888
content-length: 1115

--------------------------161413078116998145311888
Content-Disposition: form-data; json="{ "destinationProtocol" : "HL7", "destinationFormat": "HL7_V2_ORU", "destinationType": "example", "destinationConnectionParams":{ "URI": "example", "HOST": "example", "PORT": "example" } }"

anonymous
--------------------------161413078116998145311888
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="/path/to/file/in/localsystem.HL7”
Content-Type: text/plain

contents of the file
--------------------------161413078116998145311888--
```

This doesn't seem to be working though, it doesn't look right to me. I am pretty new to Nifi. Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong or give some insights on how to handle this properly? Thanks!

I have instead tried to use an ExecuteStreamCommand processor to simply run the curl command with command arguments -

```
-X POST;"https://example.hostname:port/delivery/deliverPackage?json=%7B%20%22destinationProtocol%22%20%3A%20%22HL7%22%2C%20%22destinationFormat%22%3A%20%22HL7_V2_ORU%22%2C%20%22destinationType%22%3A%20%22example%22%2C%20%22destinationConnectionParams%22%3A%7B%20%22URI%22%3A%20%22example%3A%2F%2Fexample%3A15050%22%2C%20%22HOST%22%3A%20%22example%22%2C%20%22PORT%22%3A%20%22example%22%20%7D%20%7D";-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data";-F "file=@/path/to/file/in/localsystem.HL7";
```

This works, but I wanted to know how to do it using the InvokeHttp processor. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using **GenerateFlowFile --> InvokeHTTP**.

The **GenerateFlowFile** would create the payload(in your case the content of localsystem.HL7) of your post in the Custom Text filed.

The **InvokeHTTP** will need to have Content-Type as ${mime.type} - default value and

Then see what the output is after your POST
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried doing that but it still throws 406 - Not Acceptable error. I checked the logs of the API service and it says: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request.