# POST a JSON and a CSV in a multipart/form-data request through a NiFi 1.15 InvokeHTTP processor

Tags: http-post, apache-nifi, multipartform-data

I'm working on a NiFi 1.15 flow where I have to send a request to a service that requires 2 pieces of form-data sent in a POST request as a multipart/form-data. The first part is a simple JSON object with a few parameters, while the second part is a CSV file. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=1cf28ed799fe4325b8cd0637a67dc612


--1cf28ed799fe4325b8cd0637a67dc612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="json"; filename="json"

{"Param1": "Value1","Param2": "Value2","Param3": true}
--1cf28ed799fe4325b8cd0637a67dc612
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="body.csv"

Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4,Field5
VALUE_FIELD_1,VALUE_FIELD_2,VALUE_FIELD_3,"Some value for field 4",VALUE_FIELD_5

--1cf28ed799fe4325b8cd0637a67dc612--
```

Another acceptable output would have the `Content-Disposition` lines empty.

Due to a few restrictions in the environment I am working on, I am not allowed to use scripting processors, such as ExecuteGroovyScript as [suggested in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374728/posting-multiple-files-using-invokehttp-to-api-using-nifi).

Instead, I started creating a `GenerateFlowFile -> InvokeHTTP` flow. The GenerateFlowFile would output to a flow file a text similar to the one mentioned above. Here is the screenshot of the GenerateFlowFile.

[image: Configuration of the GenerateFlowFile]

The connected InvokeHTTP processor is configured to use the **POST** Http Method and to send headers (the Authorization header in my case) and Send Message Body is set to true. It also extracts the Content-Type from the flow file previsously generated attribute through a ${mime.type} function. You can see the details in the following screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Sadly, this does not work. The server responds with an "Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete." error.

After searching for a while in SO, I [found another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56062323/how-to-send-an-http-post-multipart-form-data-request-with-a-file-attached-using) describing what looks like a similar problem, but there they are getting a different error and is also posting parameters through a different method.

I am also aware about the [blog post from Otto Fowler](https://palindromicity.blogspot.com/2020/04/sending-multipart-form-data-with.html) where he shows how InvokeHTTP supports POSTs with multipart/form-data. I did try this approach too, but did not manage to get it working. The service throws an error stating that NiFi does not send one of my `post:form:part`s.

Right now I am stuck and am not able to send that data. I did manage to write a simple Python script to test if the server is working properly and it is. For reference, here is the script:

```
import requests
server = 'https://targetserver.com'

#Authentication
result = requests.post(server + '/authentication',
                       {'grant_type': 'password',
                        'username': 'username',
                        'password': 'password'})
token = result.json()['access_token']

#Build the request
headers = {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + token}
json_data = '{"Param1": "Value1","Param2": "Value2","Param3": true}'

# First the JSON then the csv file.
files = {'json': json_data,
         'file': open('body.csv', 'rb')}
result = requests.post(server + '/endpoint', headers = headers, files = files)
print(result.text)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to get around this situation?

Comment: the error `Unexpected end of MIME multipart stream. MIME multipart message is not complete.` saying that the body is incorrect. so you put something wrong into body. btw there is a smaller script to build multipart correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57122809/nifi-multipart-form/57204862#57204862

Comment: without sharing the body we can't help. the delimiter between http headers must be CRLF - this could be an issue when using generateFlowFile

Comment: I managed to solve this issue. The problem was related with CRLF and some message formatting issue. Thanks @daggett.